# Global section of the line bundle ${\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_k}(1)$ over ${\Bbb P}_k^1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, projective-space, line-bundles

The total space of the very ample line bundle ${\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_k^1}(1)$ over ${\Bbb P}_k^1$ is the complement $T \colon= {\Bbb P}_k^2 \setminus {x}$ of a point $x$ in a projective surface, where $x = (1 \colon 0 \colon 0) \in {\Bbb P}_k^2$ and ${\Bbb P}_k^1 = (0 \,\colon k\,\colon k) \hookrightarrow {\Bbb P}_k^2 = (k \,\colon k \,\colon k)$. That is we have the fibration

\begin{equation*}
\pi \colon T \to {\Bbb P}_k^1
\end{equation*}

Q. How can one *visualise* an everywhere holomorphic section of ${\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_k^1}(1)$ as the section $s \colon {\Bbb P}_k^1 \to T$ to $\pi$ in the above context ?

I have difficulty to figure out the everywhere holomorphic section, i.e. locally holomorphic function which glues globally on ${\Bbb P}_k^1$. Any hint will be extremely helpful.

Comment: In this context, a section of $\pi$ is given by a line in $T$. The line given by vanishing of the first coordinate is the zero section, and any other line intersects the zero section in a unique point. To actually map a point $p \in \mathbb P^1$ to its image under $s$, draw a line between $p$ (considered as a line in $T$) and $x$; this is the fiber over $p$, and its intersection with the line corresponding to $s$ is $s(p)$.

Comment: Great thanks! Quite beautiful answer. Pierre

Comment: OK, I will record it as such.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, a section of $\pi$ is given by a line in $T$: the line given by vanishing of the first coordinate is the zero section, and any other line intersects the zero section in a unique point. To actually map a point $p \in \mathbb P^1$ to its image under $s$, draw a line between $p$ (considered as a point in $T$) and $x$; this is the fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$, and its intersection with the line corresponding to $s$ is $s(p)$.

Comment: Dear Tabes, can you explain how $s(p) \in \pi^{-1}(p)$ is explicitly viewed in $k$? That is, $T$ is locally isomorphic to $U \times {\mathrm{Spec}}\, k[Y]$, i.e. an affine line. Thus after leaving the zero section out therefrom, we obtain $U \times {\mathrm{Spec}} \,k[Y, 1/Y]$, i.e. $U \times {\Bbb G}_m$. Thus $T$ is a ${\Bbb G}_m$-torsor. I have difficult viewing the section $s$ as a locally holomorphic function from $U$ to the fibre ${\mathrm{Spec}}\, k[Y]$. I think I am missing the transition function. What's an easy but concrete example of $s$ as a holomorphic function on each affine $U$?

Comment: Let $(X:Y:Z)$ be homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb P^2$. Then $T$ is the complement of $(1:0:0)$ and the zero section is $X=0$. If I pass to the open affine $V\subset\mathbb P^2$ given by $Z \ne 0$, then $y = Y/Z$ is the coordinate in the "fiber direction." So any nonconstant linear function in $x=X/Z$ is a section over $U$ (which again here is $\left\{X=0\right\}\cap\left\{Z\ne 0\right\}$). Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed a few things up. The fiber direction coordinate is $x = X/Z$, and the sections over $U$ are given by linear functions in $y = Y/Z$ (and actually constants are OK; $x = 3$ is obviously disjoint from the zero section over $U$, but will intersect it at $\infty$).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** If $V:=k\{e_0,e_1\}$ is a 2-dimensional vector space over $k$ with dual space $V^*:=k\{x_0,x_1\}$ it follows there is a canonical isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces

$$H^0(\mathbb{P}(V^*), \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V^*)}(1) ) \cong V^*.$$

Here $x_i:=e_i^*$ is the dual basis.
Hence a global section $s$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V^*)}(1)$   corresponds 1-1 to an element

$$s:=s_0x_0+s_1x_2 \in V^*$$

which is a map

$$s:V \rightarrow k.$$

The element $s$ may be zero, hence $s$ does not always span a "line" in $V^*$.

**Note:** You may construct the "geometric vector bundle" $\mathcal{L}_d:=\mathbb{V}(L_d^*)$ for any linebundle $L_d:=\mathcal{O}(d)$ on $C:=\mathbb{P}^1$ and by definition

$$\mathcal{L}_d:=Spec(Sym_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}^*(L_d^*)) \cong Spec(Sym_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}^*(L_{-d}))  .$$

There is a canonical projection map $\pi_d: \mathcal{L}_d: \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ and you must prove there is an "equality" between the set of sections $s:\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathcal{L}_1$ of $\pi_1$ and the $k$-vector space $V^*$. More generally it follows the set of sections of the map $\pi_d: L_d \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_k$ equals $Sym^d(V^*)$.
Note that the geometric vector bundle $L_d$  is locally trivial: $\pi^{-1}(D(x_i)) \cong D(x_i) \times \mathbb{A}^1_k$, where $\mathbb{A}^1_k \cong D(x_i)\subseteq \mathbb{P}^1_k$ is the standard open cover. If $x\in \mathbb{P}^1_k$ is a point and $\pi^{-1}(x) \cong \mathbb{A}^1_{\kappa(x)}$ is the fiber it follows the zero-section $s(0):=0\in Sym^d(V^*)$ corresponds to the zero section $s_0$ of $\pi_d$: It is the section that maps $x$ to the origin $(0)\in \mathbb{A}^1_{\kappa(x)}$ for all $x$.

**Note:** For a real smooth vector bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ of a real smooth manifold $M$, two smooth sections $s,t$ may be "added": For any point $x\in M$ let $(s+t)(x):=s(x)+t(x)\in E_x$. The fiber $E_x$ is a real vector space and you may add sections fiberwise and you get a global section $s+t\in H^0(M,E)$. It follows the set of global section $H^0(M,E)$ is a real vector space. In the above situation the fiber $\pi_d^{-1}(x) \cong \mathbb{A}^1_{\kappa(x)}$ is not a vector space, but you still get a $k$-vector space structure on the set of global section of $L_d$.

In general if $X:=Spec(A)$ is an affine scheme and $E$ is a finite rank locally trivial $A$-module, it follows

$$\pi_E:\mathbb{V}(E^*):=Spec(Sym^*_A(E^*))\rightarrow X$$

is a "geometric vector bundle" on $X$. The set of global sections of $\pi_E$ equals $E$, hence the set of global sections is an $A$-module.

Comment: Your explanation has something to do with Serre's twisted sheaf, doesn't it? Anyhow, I would like to understand visually what is the global section. In terms of Tabes' answer in the above, how $x_0 \in V^*$ corresponds to the line in $T$?

Comment: @PierreMATSUMI - In Hartshorne Ex.II.5.18 they prove the existence of an equivalence of categories between the category of finite rank geometric vector bundles on a scheme $X$ and the category of finite rank locally trivial sheaves. Given a finite rank locally trivial sheaf $E$ on $X$ there is a 1-1 correspondence between the set of sections $s$ of the projection morphism $\pi_E$ and the set of global sections $H^0(X,E)$.