# Intuitive concept of Levi-Civita connection.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, line-bundles

For the line bundle $L$ over a manifold $M$, the connection $\nabla \colon L \to \Omega_M^1 \otimes L$ is defined. To the best of my knowledge when $L$ is a trivial line bundle ${\cal O}_M$, $\nabla$ descends to the usual differential $d \colon {\cal O}_M \to \Omega_M^1$. I cannot make head or trail of what $\nabla$ is all about for a general line bundle $L$.

In order to fix the idea, let us choose a very ample line bundle $L \colon= {\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1}(1)$ of the projective line ${\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1$ whose total space is ${{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}}^2 \setminus {(0,0,1)}$. The global section of ${\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1}(1)$ is the circle on ${\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^2$ which does *not* pass through $(0,0,1)$. c.f. [Global section of the line bundle ${\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_k}(1)$ over ${\Bbb P}_k^1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226709/global-section-of-the-line-bundle-cal-o-bbb-p-k1-over-bbb-p-k1/4226964?noredirect=1#comment8780808_4226964)

Q. What is the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ for $L = {\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{{\Bbb C}}^1}(1)$? Is there any intuitive figure of $\nabla \colon {\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1}(1) \to \Omega_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1} \otimes_{{\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}}^1} \!\!\!{\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1}(1)$ in view of the global section $s$, i.e., circle on ${\Bbb P}_{{\Bbb C}}^2$, of ${\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1}(1)$? What if we choose other connection if it should exist?

Comment: The Levi-Civita connection is a connection on the tangent bundle, not on arbitrary line bundles. In this case $T_{\mathbb P^1} \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(2)$.

Comment: Also, Levi-Civita connection is defined for a Riemannian metric, what you have instead is a complex structure on your bundle. It seems that your questions stem from difficulty absorbing the definition of a connection. Is there any setting (besides trivial bundles) where you are comfortable with this notion? Maybe affine connections on tangent bundles?

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** What is the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ for $L = {\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{{\Bbb C}}^1}(1)$? Is there any intuitive figure of $\nabla \colon {\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1}(1) \to \Omega_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1} \otimes_{{\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}}^1} \!\!\!{\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1}(1)$ in view of the global section $s$, i.e., circle on ${\Bbb P}_{{\Bbb C}}^2$, of ${\cal O}_{{\Bbb P}_{\Bbb C}^1}(1)$? What if we choose other connection if it should exist?

**Answer:** The Levi-Civita connection is defined for the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold - it is by definition the unique connection compatible with the  Riemannian metric.

Your eample above asks for an example of a connection a line bundle $L(d):=\mathcal{O}(d)$ with $d=1$ on the complex projective line $C:=\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$. Let $k:=\mathbb{C}$. There is the well known Atiyah sequence

$$(*)\text{  } 0 \rightarrow \Omega^1_{C/k}\otimes L(d) \rightarrow J^1(L(d)) \rightarrow L(d) \rightarrow 0$$

which is an exact sequence of left $\mathcal{O}_C$-modules. It is split by a holomorphic connection

$$\nabla: L(d) \rightarrow \Omega^1_{C/k} \otimes L(d).$$

In the case when $d=1$ it follows the sequnce does not split, hence $L(1)$ does not have a holomorphic connection. For the projective line it follows $\Omega^1_{C/k} \cong L(-2)$ and you may check this claim by explicit calculations. If a line bundle $L$ on a curve  $C$ has a connection it follows the set of connections on $L$ is the set

$$ Hom_{\mathcal{O}_C}(L, \Omega^1_{C/k}\otimes L) \cong Hom_{\mathcal{O}_C}(\mathcal{O}_C, \Omega^1_{C/k}) \cong H^0(C, \Omega^1_{C/k})$$

and in the case of the projective line this is equals $(0)$ since $\Omega^1_{C/k} \cong L(-2)$.

**Note:** You should specify: Do you view the complex projective line $C$ as a complex manifold or as a real smooth manifold (or scheme over $\mathbb{R}$)? The Weil restriction of the complex projective line is isomorphic to the real 2-sphere:

$$Res_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}) \cong S(2),$$

and the real smooth vector bundle $E$ associated to $L(1)$ is a real rank 2 smooth vector bundle on $S(2)$, and this always has a smooth connection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection